# Why does my rsync not allow block-size>128K?

Tags: rsync

Running rsync with a large<sup>*</sup> `--block-size` like this:

```
rsync -avvz --rsh 'ssh -c arcfour' --block-size 1048576 --inplace --progress example.com:/big.file /big.file
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid block length 1048576 [sender]
```

Both ends are running 64bit CentOS 6.4. From Googling I've seen `--block-size` used with much higher values, why is this not working for me?

<sub>* *I'm using a large block size because I'm trying to work around a bug where rsync just spins CPU forever 44% into a 300GB file*</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the source](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=io.c;h=3036903c4d2986dee4532ff6ed61c64452a7075f;hb=HEAD#l1898):

```
int32 max_blength = protocol_version < 30 ? OLD_MAX_BLOCK_SIZE : MAX_BLOCK_SIZE;

sum->blength = read_int(f);
if (sum->blength < 0 || sum->blength > max_blength) {
    rprintf(FERROR, "Invalid block length %ld [%s]\n",
        (long)sum->blength, who_am_i());
    exit_cleanup(RERR_PROTOCOL);
}
```

[Where](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=rsync.h;h=714906a6f1a439b2192c5c147ee9021e999219d2;hb=HEAD#l139):

```
#define OLD_MAX_BLOCK_SIZE ((int32)1 << 29)
#define MAX_BLOCK_SIZE ((int32)1 << 17)
```

Which is `536870912` (512M) and `131072` (128k) respectively.

---

The change was made in version [v3.0.0](http://git.samba.org/rsync.git/?p=rsync.git;a=patch;h=f264662f71d65a8addc50d3ee0372d82c903bf2a) and support for `OLD_` was [added in v3.0.3](http://git.samba.org/rsync.git/?p=rsync.git;a=patch;h=8bd77e7098d9863f258070fb2274e324a446adbd). (Links explain some of the rationale behind the changes.)

- [PATCH] A patch to try to make really large files get handled without bogging
  down in sender-side hashtable searching.
- [PATCH] Fixed the sending of large files with older rsync versions by
  handling the old block-size limit for protocols < 29.

Comment: There still seems to be a bug in 3.0.x in block size handling under --dry-run.  A command without --dry-run can work, but with it still results in the "Invalid block length NNN [sender]" message.

Comment: Fascinating that I just encountered the nuance mentioned by @PaulGear, over 3 years later and this is still an issue in Ubuntu 18 with ? v3.1.2

Answer (score 3):

The maximum block size depends on the rsync protocol version.

With protocol version less than 30, the max was `1 << 29`, i.e. 536870912 bytes (512M). But with protocol version 30 or above, the max is `1 << 17`, which is 128k bytes. So you'll need to use an older version if you want larger block sizes.

Source: [rsync.h](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=rsync.h;h=714906a6f1a439b2192c5c147ee9021e999219d2;hb=HEAD#l139)

```
#define MAX_BLOCK_SIZE ((int32)1 << 17)

/* For compatibility with older rsyncs */
#define OLD_MAX_BLOCK_SIZE ((int32)1 << 29)
```

And: [io.c](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=io.c;h=3036903c4d2986dee4532ff6ed61c64452a7075f;hb=HEAD#l1898)

```
// ...
int32 max_blength = protocol_version < 30 ? OLD_MAX_BLOCK_SIZE : MAX_BLOCK_SIZE;
// ...
if (sum->blength < 0 || sum->blength > max_blength) {
  rprintf(FERROR, "Invalid block length %ld [%s]\n",
                  (long)sum->blength, who_am_i());
```